# RPMDB broke after a yum update in fedora 19?

Tags: fedora, yum, rpm

A `sudo yum update` operation got interrupted and after a `yum-complete-transaction` was tried again I got this message:

> Transaction check error: file /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pac from install
>   of sssd-ipa-1.11.0-1.fc19.x86_64 conflicts with file from package
>   sssd-ad-1.11.0-0.2.beta2.fc19.x86_64

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be tempted to try the following:

1. Clean all

   ```
   $ yum clean all
   $ yum update -y 
   -or-
   $ yum-complete-transaction
   ```
2. Remove/Reinstall

   ```
   $ yum remove sssd-ipa sssd-ad
   $ yum install sssd-ipa sssd-ad
   ```